# Create network shared folder using Powershell on Windows 7

Tags: powershell, network-share

I need to create a shared network folder on windows 7 using PowerShell - I cant get access to New-SmbShare as this is for windows 8 and Windows 2012 Server - any examples would be great.

Am I limited to WMI calls?

Answer (score 3):

Copy-paste ready version:

```
function New-Share ($foldername, $sharename) { 
    if (!(test-path $foldername)) { 
        new-item $foldername -type Directory } 

    if (!(get-wmiObject Win32_Share -filter “name='$sharename'”)) { 
        $shares = [WMICLASS]”WIN32_Share”

        if ($shares.Create($foldername, $sharename, 0).ReturnValue -ne 0) {
            throw "Failed to create file share '$sharename'"
        }
    }    
}
```

Answer (score 1):

First hit on Google for "create shared folder powershell" is titled: [How to Use PowerShell to Create Shared Folders in Windows 7](http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2010/09/16/how-to-use-powershell-to-create-shared-folders-in-windows-7.aspx), and lays it out step by step.

```
Function NEW-SHARE ($Foldername, $Sharename) {

                # Test for existence of folder, if not there then create it
                #
                IF (!(TEST-PATH $Foldername)) {
                                NEW-ITEM $Foldername -type Directory }

# Create Share but check to make sure it isn’t already there
#
If (!(GET-WMIOBJECT Win32_Share -filter “name=$Sharename”) {
                $Shares.Create($Foldername,$Sharename,0)
}

}
```

Comment: I don't see where your code initializes the $Shares variable.

Comment: @MikeShepard Not my code - follow the link to the article it comes from.  But yeah, looks like they left out a `$Shares=[WMICLASS]"WIN32_Share"` ... not to mention a couple closing braces.  Sloppy work, Scripting Guy.

Comment: I actually followed the link to see what the answer was because I was curious.  For completeness' sake, I'd edit the answer to include that information.